# Autodoc Inheritance - Don't show members from 'Object'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I'm using `autodoc` to document some classes and so far, `:members:`, `:private-members:`, and `:special-members:` get me exactly what I want. However, I would also like to see members that are inherited.

There is an additional option, `:inherited-members:`, which gives me all those things I want... And a bunch of other crap I *don't* want, because it shows members inherited from **Object**.

Is there a way to get it to ignore members inherited from certain parents, or to only follow the inheritance chain as far up as my own defined classes, not ones that are built-in?

Answer (score 0):

It'll be possible in Sphinx 3: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/5923